# Custom url rewriting

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I am struggling to create custom rewrite rules for wordpress.

This is my url structure

```
http://domain/cityprofile/?city=Sydney
```

where city profile is a page template.

Now i want to make this url as

```
http://domain/Sydney
```

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I would like to get answer from the downvoter...

Comment: Define `RewriteBase ` as per your domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>**[answer updated as wanted]**</s>

It's better to hook your function to `generate_rewrite_rules` so you won't have fall into infinite loops and flushing rewrite rule on every request. So you can do this:

```
function add_my_rules($wp_rewrite) 
{
    $new_rules = array(
        '^cityprofile/\?city=(Sydeny|Melbourne|Brisbane)$' => $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) // for 3 cities
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_my_rules');
```

and then regenerate structure by going to `Permalinks structure` section and doing an update.

Note that this will redirect `http://domain.com/cityprofile/?city=Sydney`to `http://domain.com/Sydney` but if you mean redirection from second URL to the first one I should say that it's not possible because it doesn't have somthing particular and clear in url to write a specefic pattern and will effect all other urls as well.

*So my suggestion:*

You can make your url more structural and understandable by adding a rewrite rule for `http://domain.com/city/Sydney` that opens up `http://domain.com/cityprofile/?city=Sydeny`

**Update #2**

Replace this rules with previous ones in .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(Sydney|Melbourne|Brisbane)$ cityprofile/?city=$1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Still no luck dear :-( not working for http://fca.siteprogress.info/Sydney

Comment: What can be wrong here mate, is there any server issue that not allowing this.

Comment: @Pramod I updated again. replace all lines again

Comment: Nothing happen dear...

Comment: @Pramod hmmm so it's not about htaccess rules, I tested it here http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ it works.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks mate for your all help. Many thanks :-)

Comment: @Pramod so what was the problem?

Comment: ,htaccess not running on myserver

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do know that this will collide with pages (and when having permalink set to `%postname%`, posts as well) that have the same name as some city, right?

That being said, put the following in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^cityprofile/(.*)city=([^&]*)(.*)',
    '$matches[2]/$matches[1]$matches[3]',
    'top'
);
```

**What does it do?**

- take an URL that is

  - starting with `cityprofile/`
  - having the `city` query var set
- rewrite the URL as desired
- account for other query vars that might be present

If you don't want to account for other query vars the following should do already:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^cityprofile/(.*)city=([^&]*)',
    '$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

Comment: Its still not working http://fca.siteprogress.info/Sydney